# How to pass the value of ng-model in two different controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `ng-model` and I want its value to be accessed from two different controllers. I know that the way to share data between two different controllers is by using a `service`. But I cannot use the value of `ng-model` to a service but only from the controller.

Comment: Where is the model data stored?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the two controller div's in a mutual parent and then $watch() for the the change of that model and then $emit() the changes to the child controllers when changes is watched in $watch()

links for reference

[$watch reference](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2658-using-scope-watch-to-watch-functions-in-angularjs.htm)

[$emit reference](http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use rootscope to access that ng-model variable.but it is not a good practice.

```
<input ng-model="mk" type="text">
```

in controller :

```
$rootScope.mk=$scope.mk;
```

and access this in other controller as `$rootScope.mk`

Note:you have to inject $rootScope in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Why can you not use a service? Services are precisely the way you share data across different parts of the application. You can achieve this by exposing your service on each controller and binding `ng-model` to that service.

JS

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .factory('User', [function () {
    var service = {
      username: null
    };
    return service;
  }])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'User', function ($scope, User) {
    $scope.User = User;
  }])
  .controller('SecondCtrl', ['$scope', 'User', function ($scope, User) {
    $scope.User = User;
  }]);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="User.username">
</div>
<div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="User.username">
</div>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/VSEHD970O0xWbu6OCPqB?p=preview